# Why can't I use final fields within an instance initializer block?

Tags: java, initializer

From Oracle's [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), *Initializing Fields* (emphasis mine):

> The Java compiler **copies initializer blocks into every constructor**. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

Also, from DOJ's [article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html) about instance initializers in Java (emphasis mine):

> Instance initialization block code runs right after the call to super() in a constructor, in other words, **after all super constructors have run**.

Putting that into consideration, why does my compiler warns me every time I'm trying to use an (assigned) final fields within the instance initializer block like below?

```
final class PpTitleBook implements TitleBook {
  private final Resources resources;
  private final Log log;

  PpTitleBook(Resources resources, Log log) {
    this.resources = resources;
    this.log = log;
  }

  {
    String[] resTitles = resources.getStringArray(R.array.titles);

    if (book().getAllKeys().isEmpty()) {
      for (int i = 0; i < resTitles.length; i++) {
        newTitle(resTitles[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have no other constructor beside the one shown above. So what's the real reason behind the warning?

Comment: The answer is in the question: *Instance initialization block code runs right after the call to super() in a constructor* so, before the remaining code of the constructor, initializing the final field, is executed. And that's exactly what the warning message is telling, too.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593606/how-non-static-initializer-block-invoked?rq=1 (the question is bad, but the answers are ok)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instance initializer block code is executed before the code of the constructor, so your `resources` variable is not initialized before being used by the instance initializer block.

Since you only have one constructor, you can just move the code of the instance initializer block to the constructor.

Comment: I was confused with the word "copies initializer blocks into every constructor" in Oracle's docs. Oh, and there used to be more than one ctor on said class. I'm in the process of refactoring and this occurrence struck my curiosity. Thanks.